# WebClient C# terminando download antes de começar a baixar

Tags: c#, download, porcentagem, webclient

estou com uma dúvida, estou usando o WebClient na linguagem C#, estou com o seguinte problema: Eu clico em Baixar um arquivo, e ele não começa a baixar, ele diz que download já está terminado...

Código:

```
WebClient Web = new WebClient();
                string Info = Web.DownloadString("https://drive.google.com/uc?authuser=0&id=1_bujHdC26AyVeFUZc-5UbDV-g8UuGdXS&export=download");
                string VAtualizada = Info.Split('\n')[0];
                V1 = VAtualizada.Split('.')[0];
                V2 = VAtualizada.Split('.')[1];
                V3 = VAtualizada.Split('.')[2];
                metroLabel2.Text = "Versão mais recente: V" + VAtualizada;
                frmGerador.Versao = VAtualizada;
                Web.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(Web_DownloadProgress);
                Web.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(Web_DownloadCompleted);
                Web.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(Info.Split('\n')[1]), Application.StartupPath + @"\Gerador de Deck V" + V1 + "." + V2 + "." + V3 + " - Clash Royale.exe");
```

Evento DownloadFileCompleted:

```
void Web_DownloadCompleted(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
                MessageBox.Show("A nova versão foi baixada com sucesso." + Environment.NewLine + "O programa será reiniciado.", "Atualização", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }
```

Alguém pode me dizer o por quê do erro? E também no evento DownloadProgress eu só consigo obter a seguinte informação: e.BytesReceived

Código:

```
void Web_DownloadProgress(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            metroLabel5.Text = "Baixado: " + e.BytesReceived / 1024 + "KB";
        }
```

Resumindo minhas dúvidas até aqui:
- Ao clicar em Download, o arquivo diz: "Nova versão baixada com sucesso." sem ter baixado. (Antes estava normal, agora não)
- Não consigo usar as Propriedades e.TotalBytesToReceive nem e.ProgressPorcentage no método DownloadProgress

Alguém pode me ajudar? Comente aqui em baixo qualquer dúvida!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provavelmente por que o método DownloadFileAsync está suprimindo algum erro, o seu split não está quebrando corretamente o retorno da string e a url de download está na terceira posição do array, fiz algumas alterações e adicionei o using porque você não estava fazendo o Dispose do WebClient também.

Depois vem o outro detalhe, DownloadFileAsync é um método assíncrono então, ele não bloqueia a thread e você precisa esperar pelo fim de sua execução.

```
using (WebClient Web = new WebClient())
{        
    var taskNotifier = new AutoResetEvent(false);        

    string Info = Web.DownloadString("https://drive.google.com/uc?authuser=0&id=1_bujHdC26AyVeFUZc-5UbDV-g8UuGdXS&export=download");

    //Split pela quebra de linha \r\n
    string[] data = Info.Split(Environment.NewLine.ToCharArray());
    string VAtualizada = data[0];

    //Se não houver valor na segunda posição ele pega a da terceira
    //Adicione o tratamento que achar mais adequado;
    string url = string.IsNullOrEmpty(data[1]) ? data[1] : data[2];

    V1 = VAtualizada.Split('.')[0];
    V2 = VAtualizada.Split('.')[1];
    V3 = VAtualizada.Split('.')[2];
    metroLabel2.Text = "Versão mais recente: V" + VAtualizada;
    frmGerador.Versao = VAtualizada;

    Web.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(Web_DownloadProgress);
    Web.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(Web_DownloadCompleted);

    //Bloco try/catch para a captura e interrupção no caso de algum erro
    try
    {
        Web.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(url), Application.StartupPath + @"\Gerador de Deck V" + V1 + "." + V2 + "." + V3 + " - Clash Royale.exe");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw e;
    }        

    taskNotifier.WaitOne();

}
```

Comment: Olá amigo! Obrigado pela ajuda, eu consegui resolver! Vou explicar o que estava acontecendo.

Estava tudo correto o download, tudo certinho. O problema que ocorria que eu clicava em baixar, e já dizia "Baixado com sucesso" sem ter baixado, era por que variáveis V1, V2 e V3 era strings, foi eu mudar para tipo inteiro, que começou a baixar!
Já o erro que não eu não conseguia usar as propriedades e.TotalBytesToReceive e nem e.ProgressPorcentage, era por que eu tava baixando arquivos pelo Google Drive (??), foi só eu mudar para o MediaFire, que funcionou tudo corretamente! Dicas, comente aqui;